# TypeError: Cannot create property 'message' on string Toastr error using Angular

Tags: angular, ngx-toastr

I am using some open source code that is a couple of years old to create a blog. The Source code was created using with Angular v 11 and an earlier version of Toastr to create error messages. I have Angular v 13 on my machine but haven't had any problems making the API for the project. Now I am getting this error when I try to build the front end after adding an error interceptor:

> ./node_modules/ngx-toastr/fesm2015/ngx-toastr.mjs - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js):
> TypeError: Cannot create property 'message' on string 'C:\Users\benja\CroweQuest\CroweQuest-UI\node_modules\ngx-toastr\fesm2015\ngx-toastr.mjs: This application depends upon a library published using Angular version 14.0.2, which requires Angular version 14.0.0 or newer to work correctly.
> Consider upgrading your application to use a more recent version of Angular.

If I upgrade to v 14 of Angular it gives me many other problems with the source code that I would not rather try to dig into to fix. I have tried going backward in Angular to v 11 but that didn't work. I also have tried to run `npm --legacy-peer-deps`, but that doesn't work either.

Is there a way to go back to an earlier version of Toastr?

Here are some full screenshots of the error:
[Screen shot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fiSF.png)

[Second part of error screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGDIa.png)

Is there a way to go to an earlier version of Toastr, or how do you uninstall Toastr from your project? I have tried running npm uninstall toastr and it didn't work.

Thank you for any help you can give.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find `package.json` and revert to `"ngx-toastr": "^14.3.0"` which is compatible with Angular 13. See here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular13-toastr-c55qqy?file=package.json

Delete `node_modules` before hand.

`npm install ngx-toastr ^14.3.0 --save`

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you so much for your help. I had worked on it on my own for many hours.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is your ngx-toastr version that doesn't work with your Angular version.
[image]

Downgrade your ngx-toastr version into 14.3.0 with following commands:

- Uninstall ngx-toastr dependency: npm uninstall ngx-toastr.
- Install ngx-toastr v14.3.0: npm i ngx-toastr@14.3.0.